# I just bought a TFT screen is it still possible to use the serial port 1 and 0?

Tags: serial, tft

so I have a question regarding the TFT touch screen... I would like to use the serial ports 1 and 0 (on my UNO) to transmit data to my mega... however it take up those ports. on the back of it, it shows what each prong should occupy. However, nothing is noted to be required for those ports. is it possible to clip those prongs off and still have the screen be usable or are they important to keep?

Comment: Please edit your question, and specify the brand and model of TFT touch screen you have, when you edit the question.

Comment: Yes, need more information for any kind of definitive answer..  What kind of Touch Screen and what kind of Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use those pins. Just because there are physical pins on the shield doesn't mean they are actually used. If nothing is written next to them then yes you can use them.

Be warned though that those pins are used for communication with your PC - and that includes uploading sketches - so you may experience problems doing things like that while your Mega is connected to those pins.